# Wordpress custom CSS path

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm not sure if this is a wider issue with Wordpress or just with the HTML5 Blank theme I'm using but basically the `functions.php` is looking for `/style.css`. As I keep my CSS files in a folder I'd like the theme to mirror my static HTML templates if possible. I tried amending the line to the following:

```
function html5blank_styles()
{
    //wp_register_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    //wp_enqueue_style('normalize'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_style('html5blank', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('html5blank'); // Enqueue it!
}
```

That was the only reference to the stylesheet(s) so I thought simply changing the name/path to what I have would work but it causes the theme not to load.

Any ideas? Or am I going about this totally the wrong way?

Comment: I'd check the output in the browser and the network tab in the browser developer tools (F12), to see what is loaded exactly. Might be caused by a type in the path, or maybe because you changes a root-path (starting with `/`) to a relative path.

Comment: If I use `/css/main.css` it seems to work as long as I don't remove `style.css` from the root. As soon as I delete that Wordpress won't run the theme anymore. Strange because that path isn't looking for it. I wonder if somewhere else is looking for it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to connect additional CSS files via `wp_register_style`, but you can't delete `style.css`, because this file is necessary for the WordPress theme functionality. But if you don't need styles from this file, then you can remove all CSS code from `style.css`, but keep the data required for WordPress Theme. So your `style.css` can look like this:

```
/*
Theme Name: WP Theme name
Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/
Author: Author
Author URI: https://wordpress.org/
Description: WP Theme.
Version: 0.1
*/
```

Comment: That makes sense, I guess that file is what gives the theme it's name/data and screenshot in the appearance/theme section of the cms?

Comment: Yes, correct. You can read more about this [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hate stray files lying around so it's good to know this _still_ has a purpose even though I have my website css in a difference location!